# where does the phrase "all of a 2 'n 8" originate from?

Tags: expressions

where does the phrase "all of a 2 'n 8" originate from? It means - not knowing what to do - confused - unsettled

Comment: I've heard of being at [sixes and sevens.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sixes_and_sevens)

Comment: @Chav Yes, you're right about the meaning. It's Cockney Rhyming slang for "state" which rhymes with the "eight" in the expression _two and eight_, which in full is _two shillings and eight pence_. When the expression was first coined, we had a 3-tier currency: pounds, shillings and pence. Nowadays we just have pounds and pence. But older speakers (like me) still use the idiom in a jocular way

Comment: @BillJ - I suggest you post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

**State** in [Cockney rhyming slang](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/alternatives/252).

Usually related to a state of emotional distress or confusion.

**EDIT**: Here is @BillJ's explanation (from comments) for the original meaning before the Cockneys overloaded it :  *"... the expression two and eight, which in full is two shillings and eight pence. When the expression was first coined, we had a 3-tier currency: pounds, shillings and pence. Nowadays we just have pounds and pence."*

Comment: No, not 2x8 timber, but _two and eight_ as in _two shillings and eight pence_. See my message below to Josh.

Comment: Cheers @BillJ, ah that makes sense now ! Pre-decimal was (only slightly) before my time !

Comment: I would suggest you correct your answer.